# Finding MLE from CDF

Tags: statistics

So I have the following $CDF$ and I was wondering how will I be able to get the Maximum Likelihood Estimator since we do not have the $PDF$ to work with. The following $CDF$ is an exponential distribution that is "shifted" if you will by $L$ units where $x>L$ and $\lambda>0$.

\begin{align*}
F(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda(x - L)}
\end{align*}

If it was a $PDF$, I realize that we should account for the $n$ observations, get the likelihood function, take the log and find the maximum via derivatives but we have the $CDF$ so that is not possible. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: you can find the pdf by taking the derivative of the cdf with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF can be calculated as the derivative of the CDF. Then you sound like you know what to do!